# Optimizing the compiler for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, optimization, compiler-construction, settings, iad

The "Build" section of project info in XCode offers lots of compiler settings. I'm seeing good improvements in performance (up to about 20%) when I choose the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler with the "FASTEST-O3" setting.

Are there other settings that also improve performance when compiling for the iPhone?

Comment: Switching on "Link-Time Optimization" with LLVM helps a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using lots of floating-point operations, it may be help to turn off `compile for Thumb` for the ARMv6 architecture.